# Q2() Function keeps looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm making a simple menu for students to see and admins to login.

```
def main():
    while(True):
        print("1. Display Class")
        print("2. Admin Login")    

        a = input("Please enter a choice or q to quit: ")
        if a=="1":
            Q1()
        elif a=="2":
            Q2()
        elif a=="q":
            break

def Q1():
    print('Class A in Room 1, Class B in Room 2')

def Q2():
    passwd = {'admin1': Q2}

    user_input = input("Enter administrator password: ")
    if user_input in passwd:
        func = passwd[user_input]
        func()
        print ('Success')

    else:
        print("Incorrect password")


main()
print("Goodbye")
```

The Q2() function does not work as I intended. It keeps looping "Enter administrator password: " when password is entered correctly.

Comment: Well yeah, that's what you told it to do. The question is why. What is the purpose of the `func = passwd[user_input] ; func()` block?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including expected output, i.e. what you intend `Q2()` to do.

Comment: What is the point of `passwd[user_input]`?  That is a _reference_ to the Q2 function, but it doesn't _call_ it.  It does nothing.

Comment: ok got it guys. i took a look again and yes passwd[user_input] doesn't do anything so I remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct?

```
def Q2():
    passwd = {'admin1','admin2','admin3'}
    user_input = input("Enter administrator password: ")
    if user_input in passwd:
        print ('Success')
    else:
        print("Incorrect password")
```

Comment: OK, that fixes the problem, but how does it answer the question? Like, what's the point of looking up `passwd[user_input]`? And why does `passwd` contain `Q2` anyway? Why not make `passwd` a set? `passwd = {'admin1'}`